# Can't highlight Angular material table inside material expansion panel

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular material and I have material table inside expansion panel. Here's the wired thing: I can't highlight the table.

Problem is that sometimes my users need to copy items from the table, but it just not highlight it when it inside the expansion panel.

I tried to play with it, changing things but nothing works. If I put other things though, they're selectable. I can highlight other things (paragraph, etc.) , but not the table

the code is something like:

```
...
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]= ...

    </table>

 </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to select data from a material table. Please share your relevant code or even better provide a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/github/stackblitz/starters/tree/main/angular?template=node&title=Angular%20Starter&description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20%40angular%2Fanimations%2C%20%40angular%2Fcommon%2C%20%40angular%2Fcompiler%2C%20%40angular%2Fcore%2C%20%40angular%2Fforms%2C%20%40angular%2Fplatform-browser%2C%20%40angular%2Fplatform-browser-dynamic%2C%20%40angular%2Frouter%2C%20core-js%2C%20rxjs%2C%20tslib%20and%20zone.js) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I can select data from material table across my app, it happens (that I can't select) only when it inside expansion panel